# remove div without an id tag

Tags: javascript, dom

I need a solution to remove a div without an ID tag in JavaScript only. The div looks like this `<div align="center">`.

Here is the full structure.

```
<tr id="-1">
  <td class="stxt">
    <div align="center">
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Is there any other information to go off of? Does it have a parent with an id?

Answer (score 4):

You need to work out how to get a reference to it, once you've done that, you can remove it using:

```
div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
```

Of course the *align* attribute has been deprecated, but anyway, you can find the divs with `align="center"` using:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var div;
var i = divs.length;

while (i--) {
  div = divs[i];

  if (div.getAttribute('align') == 'center') {
    div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
  }
}
```

Which will remove every div in the document that has `align="center"`.

Note that the object returned by `getElementsByTagName` is a [NodeList](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-536297177). If you iterate over it from 0 and remove nodes, they are removed from the live list so you will skip the node following the one you remove and you will attempt to access no existant nodes at the end. Going over the list backwards avoids these pitfalls. An alternative is to turn the NodeList into an array, but that's somewhat inefficient.

#### Edit

Since you edited the question, here's an update answer.

You can get a reference to the TR using *getElementById*:

```
var root = document.getElementById('-1');
```

Now you can go down the DOM:

```
var cell = root.cells[0]; // First cell in the row
var div = cell.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]; // first div
cell.removeChild(div);
```

Which is specific to the structure you've posted.

Comment: i updated the tree structure. hopefully its now easier to execute the task?

Comment: line var root = document.getElementById('tr');  
should be var root = document.getElementById('-1');

Comment: I tried your code and i had no luck. Maybe you can look at my page and see if i have the correct structure. I want to remove this text Picture -> http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/821/bc5547e311c8492b89ea358.png the url is http://pari.cbox.ws/

Comment: @sarsar - according to the [HTML 4.01 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name), id attributes must start with a letter, however browsers may tolerate other characters. The code as posted will work (with the edit suggested by Pradeep). However, the table in question is in an iframe element, so you must get a reference to the document in the iframe first, then run the function on that.

Answer (score 1):

If you can just remove the content, you can use:

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(i=0; i < all.length; i++) {
    all[i].innerHTML = ""
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/7KVkC/

Answer (score 0):

You need some way to make this div tag unique. There is another javascipt function called `getElementsByTagName` that you can use to get an array of all of the div tags. You can then use the DOM to check whether that div tag has the property of `align="center"`.